# Determine column value based on 2 other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

There are 2 column, Label1 and Label2. Both of them are cluster labels using different methods.

```
  Label1 Label2
0   0    1024
1   1    1024
2   2    1025
3   3    1026
4   3    1027
5   4    1028
```

I wanna get the final cluster label based these 2 columns. Compared each row, as long as one of these two labels are same, they are in the same cluster.

For example: row 0 and row 1 have label 2 in common, row 3 and row 4 have label1 in common, thus row0 and row1 in the same group and row3 and row4 in the same group.  So the results I'd like to have:

```
   Label1 Label2 Cluster ID
0   0    1024    0
1   1    1024    0
2   2    1025    1
3   3    1026    2
4   3    1027    2
5   4    1028    3
```

What's the best way to do this？
Any help would be appreciated.

Edited: I think I didn't give a good example. Acutally,  labels are not necessarily in any order:

```
  Label1 Label2
0   0    1024
1   1    1023
2   2    1025
3   3    1024
4   3    1027
5   4    1022
```

Comment: Could you please post code for your best attempt? Thanks

Comment: Please check this link for more help - http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this: Use np.where and [pandas.duplicated](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.duplicated.html)

```
df             = df.sort_values(['Label1', 'Label2'])
df['Cluster']  = np.where( (df.Label1.duplicated()) | (df.Label2.duplicated()),0,1).cumsum()
print df

       Label1  Label2  Cluster
0       0    1024        1
1       1    1024        1
2       2    1025        2
3       3    1026        3
4       3    1027        3
5       4    1028        4
```

Comment: Thanks. I have updated the question, my problem is that the labels column are not monotonic. The same label can appear in row1 and then row 100 and they should be clustered as the same group. Any suggestions.

Comment: I did test it, it did rely on order. Given df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Label1': [0, 1, 2, 2, 1, 3], 'Label2': [1023, 1024, 1025, 1026, 1027, 1028]}). results:1,2,3,3,3,4. However, row 1 and row 4 should be in the same group. Anyway, Thanks for you help.

Comment: Yes, you're righ,  fixed it, cumsum usage is based on order, good luck

Answer (score 2):

IIUC, you could group the clusters as follows:

Taking the difference between the row and it's next row , filling the topmost row with 0 and finding it's cumulative sum for both the Labels[1 and 2].

```
In [2]: label1_ = df['Label1'].diff().fillna(0).cumsum()

In [3]: label2_ = df['Label2'].diff().fillna(0).cumsum()
```

Concatenating these to a new dataframe and dropping the duplicated values separately for both Labels[1 and 2]. Followed by `reset_index` to get back the default integer index.

```
In [4]: df_ = pd.concat([label1_, label2_], axis=1).drop_duplicates(['Label1'])    \
                                                   .drop_duplicates(['Label2'])     \
                                                   .reset_index()
```

Assigning the index values  to a new column, Cluster ID.

```
In [5]: df_['Cluster_ID'] = df_.index

In [6]: df_.set_index('index', inplace=True)

In [7]: df['Cluster_ID'] = df_['Cluster_ID']
```

Replacing `Nan` values with it's previous finite value and casting the final answer as an integer.

```
In [8]: df.fillna(method='ffill').astype(int)
Out[8]: 
   Label1  Label2  Cluster_ID
0       0    1024           0
1       1    1024           0
2       2    1025           1
3       3    1026           2
4       3    1027           2
5       4    1028           3
```

Answer (score 1):

Not sure I've understood correctly your question but here's a possible way to identify clusters:

```
import pandas as pd
import collections

df = pd.DataFrame(
    {'Label1': [0, 1, 2, 3, 3, 4], 'Label2': [1024, 1024, 1025, 1026, 1027, 1028]})
df['Cluster ID'] = [0] * 6

counter1 = {k: v for k, v in collections.Counter(
    df['Label1']).iteritems() if v > 1}
counter1 = counter1.keys()
counter2 = {k: v for k, v in collections.Counter(
    df['Label2']).iteritems() if v > 1}
counter2 = counter2.keys()

len1 = len(counter1)
len2 = len(counter2)
index_cluster = len1 + len2

for index, row in df.iterrows():
    if row['Label2'] in counter2:
        df.loc[index, 'Cluster ID'] = counter2.index(row['Label2'])
    elif row['Label1'] in counter1:
        df.loc[index, 'Cluster ID'] = counter1.index(row['Label1']) + len2
    else:
        df.loc[index, 'Cluster ID'] = index_cluster
        index_cluster += 1

print df
```

Comment: Thanks. Would you elaborate a bit please?

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you can implement this:

1. Check previous row for same value for the two columns
2. If either of the values is same, do not increment cluster number and add to cluster list
3. If none of the values is same, increment cluster number and add to cluster list
4. Add cluster list as column to the dataframe.

Code:

```
import pandas as pd

df=pd.DataFrame([[0,1,2,3,4,5],[0,1,2,3,3,4],[1024,1024,1025,1026,1027,1028]]).T
cluster_num = 0
cluster_list = []
for i,row in df.iterrows():
    if i!=0:
        # check previous row
        if df.loc[i-1][1]==row[1] or df.loc[i-1][2]==row[2]:
            # add to previous cluster
            cluster_list.append(cluster_num)
        else:
            # create new cluster
            cluster_num+=1
            cluster_list.append(cluster_num)
    else:
        cluster_list.append(cluster_num)

#Add the list as column
df.insert(3,3,cluster_list)
```